# Vue.js Passing variable from one component to another (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, variables

I have a component called `ShowComment` and a component called `EditComment`.

In `ShowComment` there is a variable `this.CommentRecID`. I want to use this variable in the component `EditComment`.

The problem is that a `console.log(this.CommentRecID);` shows that the variable is undefined in `EditComment`, but defined in `ShowComment`, but I don't know why it's undefined:

[image]

I used this to "use" `this.CommentRecID` in `EditComment`, but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it because it's related to jquery:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import DatePicker from "vue2-datepicker";

export default {
    props: ["CommentRecID"],
    components: { DatePicker },
```

Here's the full `ShowComment` component: https://pastebin.com/fcy4PCq0

Here's the full `Editcomment` component: https://pastebin.com/uik7EwD1

I'm fairly new to Vue.js. Does someone know how one can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not use** `jQuery` and `Vue.js` at the same time.

You should try to use props to send data from parent to child.

You could add `EditComment` as an element in your `ShowComment` something like this:

```
<EditComment CommentRecID="this.CommentRecID" v-if="showEdit" />
```

And toggle the `showEdit` flag from the `editItem` method

```
editItem() {
 this.showEdit = true
}
```

If you want to show a modal, then your `EditComment` component is probably up the tree so you could either use [EventBus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) or use `Vuex`.

It seems like you are already using `Vuex` in your project, so add a mutation that stores the `CommentRecID` and use it in a similar manner to show the dialog.

Comment: Hi, thank your for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. Here's the Vuex: https://pastebin.com/57YxrSXu  Can you tell me what I need to add there use `this.CommentRecID`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Vue Props to easily solve this problem, you have to send the variable from parent component to child component, please check this `PROPS` documentation out, its self explanatory:

[Props Vuejs documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)
please let me know if you find trouble in using props

Comment: But that's what I tried when I used `props: ["CommentRecID"],`